# Airflow - Run a dag every 2h

Tags: python, airflow, airflow-scheduler

I have a dag that insert some records in MySQL table and I want to run my dag every 2h. For that I've this code:

```
from datetime import timedelta, datetime
import pymysql
import airflow
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from airflow.operators import MySqlOperator

default_args = {
 'owner': 'airflow',
 'start_date': datetime(2021, 4, 1),
 'depends_on_past': False
}

dag = DAG(dag_id='mysql_insert',
          default_args=default_args,
          schedule_interval='* */2 * * *',
          dagrun_timeout=timedelta(seconds=5))

def mysql_conn(servername, user, password, database):
    conn = pymysql.connect(user=user
                           , password=password
                           , host=servername
                           , port=3306
                           , database=database)
    return conn

conn = mysql_conn('', '', '', '')

def insert_data():
    src_cursor = conn.cursor()
    src_cursor.execute("INSERT INTO my_table VALUES('NA',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP())")
    conn.commit()

task = PythonOperator(
     task_id='insert_records'
    ,python_callable=insert_data
    ,dag=dag)

task
```

However, when I activate my dag it's loading data every 10 seconds.

What I am doing wrong?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have set `start date` as 2021-04-01 and `catchup` is not set inside dag definition so by default it is `true`.
If you look at job executions (go to Browse -> Dag runs), you will find that dag runs have started since start date and is in catch up state. You will see `execution date` starting from 2021-04-01.
If you want skip these catch up runs, please mark `catchup`  as `False` in dag arguments.